# How do I include hypens (and other special characters) in the .XCompose file?

Tags: linux, unix

I use the .XCompose file to customize my compose key shortcuts. I have a shortcut where pressing v twice produces a little checkmark: ✓

My .XCompose file looks like this:

```
include "%L"

<Multi_key> <v> <v> : "✓" U2713
```

I frequently use letters with little lines on top of them (ā, ē, ī, ō, ū), which I can get by pressing the letter and then a hyphen.

But when I press y and -, I get this: ¥
When what I really want is this: ȳ

How do I include hyphens and other special characters? Do I just type the character between <>? Do symbols have special key names? Where can I find a list of these key names?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to see what is possible is to examine the system Compose file, which for me is at `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` (even though my locale is not en_US).

You can locate the line for ¥ - I have

```
<Multi_key> <y> <minus>                 : "¥"   yen # YEN SIGN
```

as well as a number of variants, capital Y,  instead of , and the other order.

Then create a new line (or lines with the variants you want) in your .XCompose file

```
<Multi_key> <y> <minus>                 : "ȳ"
```

You will likely have to log out and in to restart X to make the changes effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the output of

```
xmodmap -pke
```